# How to put icon above image and move it to top right using Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, icons, tailwind-css

I want to make bookmark icon on top of the image using tailwind, but it seems not work for me

```
 <div class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg h-40">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9DpT.jpg" alt="placeholder" />
      <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
    </div>
```

i already try like this

```
<span class="flex absolute items-end justify-end top-2 left-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></span>
```

and use top-2 or left-2 but the icon offside from the container and also the icon always behinde the image

here is the code pen
https://codepen.io/paresiqbal/pen/yLqLRYe

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen so we can play around with your code?

Comment: I don't see anything actually appearing on the screen.